# Playframework functional test java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: playframework, functional-testing

I keep getting

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

when running my functional tests ever since I migrated to postgres from in mem db.

```
    Http.Response response = GET("/services/names/");
    assertIsOk(response);
```

Full error message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:291)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:297)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.GET(FunctionalTest.java:100)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.GET(FunctionalTest.java:54)
    at controllers.ImagesTest.shouldReturnListOfImages(ImagesTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner$StartPlay$2$1.evaluate(PlayJUnitRunner.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.run(PlayJUnitRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:101)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:220)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:278)
```

Comment: What are you doing in the "/services/name" call? Moving from mem db to PostgreSQL shouldn't break the test itself unless your model is not PostgreSQL compatible (uses reserved keywords, etc) in which case this error may be masking the real issue

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing a deadlock: the transaction in which the test runs and the one in which the action runs are conflcting as explained in the [1.2 release notes](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/releasenotes-1.2). Unfortunately, you cannot use the `READ UNCOMMITED` isolation level in PostgreSQL, since even if you specify it using `SET TRANSACTION`, [the transaction isolation level will still be `READ COMMITTED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html)

What you can do is to make sure that the transaction in the test code is committed before the transaction in the action that the test code invokes starts. For example

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
   Fixtures.loadModels("models.yml");
   JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();

  // Call a controller
}
```

An alternative is to run the tests using the in memory database.

Answer (score 1):

Functional Tests have a built-in timeout of 30 seconds hard-coded for every request
(see FunctionalTest.java:278 in Play 1.2.3). Maybe your test lasts that long on postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to increase your thread pool size. By default tests run in DEV mode, and DEV mode has a thread pool size of 1. Look for this line in your `application.conf`:

> play.pool=1

See if increasing that value will help.